# Excel IF -Then-Else condition

Tags: vba

Kindly assist to run the below Excel macro. I think i'm missing some thing. Logic not working.

```
Sub RiskGrade()

Dim Value1 As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
If (Cells(10, 2) = "BX") Then Cells(12, 4) = -8
Exit Sub

ElseIf (Cells(10, 2) = "GX") Then Cells(12, 4) = -7
Exit Sub

Else
    For i = 12 To 14

        Value1 = Right(Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)), 1)
        'MsgBox Value1
        Select Case Value1
            Case "W"
                Cells(i, 4) = 1
            Case "H", "S", "R", "F", "G"
                Cells(i, 4) = 2
            Case "D"
                Cells(i, 4) = 3
            Case "C"
                Cells(i, 4) = 4
            Case "B"
                Cells(i, 4) = 5
            Case "A"
                Cells(i, 4) = 6
            Case "*"
                Cells(i, 4) = 7
            Case "M"
                Cells(i, 4) = 8
            Case "E"
                Cells(i, 4) = 9
            Case OTHER
                Cells(i, 4) = -9
        End Select
        Exit For
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

You've started an IF statement and in the same line added an action, which means it's not going to expect an END IF or ELSE after that.

In VB

> IF condition THEN action

is a single IF statement.

Consider

```
If (Cells(10, 2) = "BX") Then
  Cells(12, 4) = -8
  Exit Sub
ElseIf (Cells(10, 2) = "GX") Then
  Cells(12, 4) = -7
  Exit Sub
...
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `Case OTHER` should be `Case Else`
2. The `Exit For` will terminate the loop after the first time through, so that needs to be removed, or changed to where you want the processing to abort
3. The `If ... Then` should be multi-line, or singleline.

   - Multi-Line:
     `If (Cells(10, 2) = "BX") Then

     Cells(12, 4) = -8

     Exit Sub

     ElseIf ...`
   - Single Line:
     `If (Cells(10, 2) = "BX") Then Cells(12, 4) = -8 : Exit Sub

     ElseIf ...`
     (note use of `:` to separate commands in same `If` statement)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OPTION EXPLICIT`, because it helps to spot errors when typos are applied to keywords.

In current shape you specified unexpected behaviour by using `Case OTHER` which should be `Case Else`, there is no keyword `OTHER` in VBA so `OTHER` is interpreted as variable of `Variant` datatype, but `Case Else` would be interpreted properly as "in other case do ...".

Also using `Exit For` after `Select` stops macro execution on `i=12`, 13 and 14 are then not applied.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RiskGrade()

Dim Value1 As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

If (Cells(10, 2) = "BX") Then 
Cells(12, 4) = -8
Exit Sub

ElseIf (Cells(10, 2) = "GX") Then 
Cells(12, 4) = -7
Exit Sub

Else
    For i = 12 To 14

        Value1 = Right(Trim(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)), 1)
        Debug.Print Value1 'CTRL+G for immediate window

        Select Case Value1
            Case "W"
                Cells(i, 4) = 1
            Case "H", "S", "R", "F", "G"
                Cells(i, 4) = 2
            Case "D"
                Cells(i, 4) = 3
            Case "C"
                Cells(i, 4) = 4
            Case "B"
                Cells(i, 4) = 5
            Case "A"
                Cells(i, 4) = 6
            Case "*" 'I don't know what behaviour in will cause, does it spot '*' only, or any char
                Cells(i, 4) = 7
            Case "M"
                Cells(i, 4) = 8
            Case "E"
                Cells(i, 4) = 9
            Case Other ' not OTHER
                Cells(i, 4) = -9
        End Select
        'Exit For ' - why exit after first iteration - guess it's unnecessary procedure ?
    Next i
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

If you remove both the "exit sub" it should work.
With the "exit sub" it seems that you are closing your if without "end if"

Comment: Don't forget to use else instead of case other

Comment: If you use the "exit for" there you are terminating your for loop at the first pass (you aren't using the for)